# I have 20 vectors, groups of 2 on an .ai artboard, how do I make these into 10 files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have one .ai artboard, it contains 20 vectors in groups of 2.

I want to create 10 separate files without having to manually create each artboard and pasting each of the 10 sets one by one.

With all the functions within .ai, I am wondering if I can slice up this one artboard into 10.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do.

1. Drag a rectangle over each of the groups of icons.
2. Select all of these new rectangles, and go to the ArtBoards panel (which is by default grouped with the Layers panel). In the upper right-hand corner, you can select "Convert to ArtBoards" from the dropdown menu.
3. Now, each rectangle will be its own ArtBoard. To export each Art Board as its own file, go to File > Save As and select 'Save Each Artboard to a Separate File.'

Viola!

Comment: Hi Bottled Smoke, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!